# How to fix memory leak issues for xamarin.Forms components.?

Tags: performance, xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Currently am creating a custom component similar to Xamarin Slider. In which i experience some memory leaks. So for testing this i created few controls in NavigationPage and moved to that page in a button click (I use Xamarin profiler to check for memory allocations). I went back the memory does not release. Also while navigating again the memory kept increasing. I have tried providing weak references, dumping with dispose methods and GC collecting.. etc.,

I replaced my custom component with the xamarin Slider. But i experience the same memory allocation problem with it.

[image]

I have pasted my sample below. Am i doing anything wrong with NavigationPages.?

[xaml]

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Button Text="SLider Page" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[cs]

```
 async void  Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new SlidertPage());
    }
```

[Slider page]

```
public class SlidertPage :ContentPage
{

    public SlidertPage()
    {

        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

        stack.Children.Add(new Slider() { HeightRequest = 200, WidthRequest = 200 });
        stack.Children.Add(new Slider() { HeightRequest = 200, WidthRequest = 200 });
        StackLayout stack2 = new StackLayout();

        stack2.Children.Add(new Slider() { HeightRequest = 200, WidthRequest = 200 });
        stack2.Children.Add(new Slider() { HeightRequest = 200, WidthRequest = 200 });

        StackLayout stack3 = new StackLayout();
        stack3.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        stack3.Children.Add(stack);
        stack3.Children.Add(stack2);
        this.Content = stack3;
    }
}
```

Please provide any suggestion to clear the allocations while the page is closed.

Comment: You can use the override `OnDisappearing` to clear out any resources in the current page before it disappears (Dispose / set to null) and manually call a `GC.Collect()`. Would highly recommend this video to help with performance tweaks as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxjOqNZFhKU